# acyclically stereocontrolled reaction: organolithium and 2-chiral compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

Aoyagi et al. ([J. Am. Chem. Soc., Vol. 115, No. 24, p 11393](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00077a044)) reported that the addition of 2-lithio-1,3-dithiane to the alpha-chiral (*S*)-2-Acetylpiperidine gives the (2 *S*,3 *S*)-configured product. It is stated that the diastereoselectivity of this 1,2-addition (*dr* = 6.2) is predicted by Cram's model involving complexation of the Li-ion by the piperidine-N. I tried to reproduce the diastereoselectivity in the following scheme:

[image: http://abload.de/img/cram-ruleseej1y.png]

As you can see I come up with the wrong product by applying Cram's rule with a O,N-complexed Li-ion (right side of the scheme). By applying the non-chelate Cram rule (left side; biggest substituent oriented anti to the carbonyl, attack via smallest group) I get the correctly configured (2 *S*,3 *S*)-product.

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I have just had a look at the paper and actually they reported that their main product was S,R:

"...treated with excess 2-lithio-1,3-dithiane in THF at -50°C; this treatment generated the tertiary alcohols 22a and 22b in 72% combined yield with 6.2:1 diastereoselectivity as predicted by Cram's model based on participation of the piperidine nitrogen atom, giving a rigid cyclic complex with the lithium compound".

Compound 22a: (2S)-2-[(R)-l-(1,3-Dithian-2-yl)-l-hydroxyethyl]piperidine

Compound 22b: (2S)-2-[(S)-1-(1,3-Dithian-2-yl)-l-hydroxyethyl]piperidine

I do not find any mistake.